# Periodic table for printing

Tags: periodic-table, reference-request

I there a *Good* Version of a printable Periodic table Which is minimalistic and gives **necessary** information only such as -

- At. Number
- Element Name
- At. weight
- Shell configuration
- color coding of various groups or Series

Comment: Whatever version you wind up finding, I would strongly suggest that you keep good track of the image file you wind up printing.  I found a really nice periodic table that I like to give to my students that includes necessary information for my courses as well as a small chart of common polyatomic ions and fundamental constants.  I've been copying the thing for years now because I can't find the original file anywhere, and the print quality is starting to suffer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [IUPAC periodic table](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/periodic-table-of-elements/) ([2016-pdf](http://iupac.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/IUPAC_Periodic_Table-28Nov16.pdf)) is good because it quantifies the accuracy of the natural abundance atomic weights, but it doesn't give electron configuration.

The [NIST periodic table](http://www.nist.gov/pml/data/periodic.cfm) has electron configuration, and probably is closest to what you want.

[image]

The NIST table is also good from a copyright point of view, because you can reproduce it without worrying about copyright infrigment, as [US government works are generally not subject to copyright protection](http://www.usa.gov/copyright.shtml).

Comment: These are both great tables; I've given my students the NIST one for a few years now. Maybe you can suggest a table that's good to include on genchem tests (American group numbers + IUPAC numbers, element name, element symbol, atomic weight, atomic number, and nothing else). I use the California Dept. of Education table (http://www.sciencegeek.net/tables/CA_CST.pdf), but it's copyrighted and it's a bit out of date.

Comment: My original answser had the old version of the Virginia periodic table http://www.doe.virginia.gov/testing/test_administration/ancilliary_materials/science/2003/2003_sol_periodic_table.pdf, because it has electron configuration (but I deleted becasue it's out of date and has wrong/less-likely configuration for Lawrencium). The newer Virginia table is very similar to California http://www.doe.virginia.gov/testing/test_administration/ancilliary_materials/science/2010/2010_sol_periodic_table.pdf (no electron configurations).

Comment: Any post-1977 work is copyrighted in USA, even if it doesn't say so, except federal works.

Answer (score 5):

The tables at [Ptable.com](http://www.ptable.com/) might well fill the bill. Here is an example:

[image]

FWIW, this is the table I use as the background for my lab computer.

Answer (score 2):

[Ptable.com](http://www.ptable.com) was already suggested, but this PDF fulfills all your requirements, and further, it has features that make it ideal for printing such as:

- Customizable information using PDF layers (supported in Acrobat)
- Low ink usage, outlines only
- Category information retained even if printed in black and white

http://www.ptable.com/print/

[image: Screenshot of Acrobat showing Ptable.com PDF with layers]